# when running npm install I am getting back npm ERR! code E404

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to run npm install and am getting Error 404 everytime. The node_modules file will show up while trying to install and then get taken away when the error comes up.

```
npm install
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://repositor.com/artifactory/api/npm/ui-mjd/whatwg-fetch/-/whatwg-fetch-3.0.0.tgz
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'whatwg-fetch@https://repository.com/artifactory/api/npm/ui-mjd/whatwg-fetch/-/whatwg-fetch-3.0.0.tgz' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

Things that I have tried:

- npm cache clean
- npm rebuild
- updating the registry
- repulling down the past working file from github

Other people are accessign the same code from github and it is working fine, but I am unable to run it through npm. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve it by running commands

```
npm update --force
npm audit fix --force
```